# Help repairing Door frame/trim repair due to pet damage

Tags: door-frame

I need some help fixing my front door. [door frame damage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dSFD.jpg)

How can i fix this damage to the door? Obviously the weather strip is easy but the actual wood is scratched up, deeper in some areas than other. Can i use a wood filler? Should i just sand it paint it and sand it again?

I have not tried anything yet. In addition the door is scratched up, not deep but noticeable. Would I need to repaint the door? Thanks!

Any help appreciated!

Thank you,

Alan

Comment: A pic of the door may help.

Comment: It's going to look a ton better with just paint. And when you go to replace the weatherstripping, take a sample with you. (There's a few flavors of that type.)